# How do I turn the say_whee function into a lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, decorator

I would like to turn `say_whee`into a lambda function.

```py
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
        func()
        print("Something is happening after the function is called.")
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    say_whee()
```

I tried this doing it as follows. However, it doesn't seem to call the function.

```py
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
        func()
        print("Something is happening after the function is called.")
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
(my_decorator(lambda x: print (x))) ("Whee")
```

Comment: Why? There's no functional (pun intended) difference between a function defined by a `def` statement and a function defined by a lambda expression. Also, `print` is already a function; you don't need to wrap it in a lambda expression to pass is as an argument to something that expects a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda is just a shortcut for writing function definitions.

Lambda version

```
say_whee = lambda : print ("Whee")
```

To apply the decorator

```
say_whee = my_decorator(lambda : print ("Whee"))
```

Full code

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
        func()
        print("Something is happening after the function is called.")
    return wrapper

say_whee = my_decorator(lambda : print ("Whee"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    say_whee()
```

Output

```
Something is happening before the function is called.
Whee
Something is happening after the function is called.
```

For clarity, `@` decorators are just syntactic sugar for applying a wrapper function.

This

```
@my_decorator
def say_whee():
    print("Whee")
```

Is the same as

```
def say_whee():
    print("Whee")
    
say_whee = my_decorator(say_whee)
```

Is the same as

```
say_whee = my_decorator(lambda : print ("Whee"))
```

Comment: Is this also possible to use with `@decorator` ?

Comment: No - The `@` syntax is only used with `def` function declarations (or classes)